# Call to a member function sayHello() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am new to Magento and following tutsplus tutorial. During module development I got this error "Call to a member function `sayHello()` on boolean".

Below is my `test.php` file in magento(for testing the module):

```
     require_once'app/Mage.php';          
     Mage::app();
     $customer= Mage::getModel("customer/session");

     //Mage_catalog_Model_Product

     Mage::getModel("catalog/product");

     $product = Mage::getModel("demo/product");

     $product -> sayHello();
```

Here is the model file code (Product.php)

```
      class Tutsplus_Demo_Model_Product {

       public function sayHello(){

       echo "Hi";
      }
     }
```

When I removed the `$product->sayHello();` to `// echo get_class($customer);` it shows the class name. config.xml file is here.

```
     <config>
       <global>
         <models>
            <demo>
                <class>Tutsplus_Demo_Model</class>
            </demo>
         </models>
       </global>
      </config>
```

Comment: Capitalize your classname with Tutsplus_Demo_Model_Product

Comment: I changed the file name 'tutsplus' to 'Tutsplus' and also class name 'tutsplus_Demo_Model_Product' to 'Tutsplus_Demo_Model_Product'. Same issue.

Comment: remove extra space in $product->sayHello();

Comment: Done. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app/etc/modules/Tutsplus_Demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <config> 
   <modules> 
    <Tutsplus_Demo> 
     <active>true</active> 
     <codePool>local</codePool> 
     <version>0.1.0</version> 
    </Tutsplus_Demo> 
   </modules> 
 </config>
```

make sure  you define  model in `app/code/local/Tutsplus/Demo/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
    <Tutsplus_Demo>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Tutsplus_Demo>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <demo>
                <class>Tutsplus_Demo_Model</class>
            </demo>
        </models>
     </global>
    </config>
```

finally your model  `app/code/local/Tutsplus/Demo/Model/Product.php`

capitalize the first keyword and extends to `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`

```
class Tutsplus_Demo_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
      public function sayHello(){

       echo "Hi";
      }

}
```

for calling the model

```
 $product = Mage::getModel("demo/product");
   $product->sayHello();
```

Comment: I changed this above code to my existing one but its still showing the same error.

Comment: can you add your module `config.xml` and `Tutsplus_Demo.xml`

Comment: yes. I did that to.

Comment: @Probe i mean add here in question

Comment: @Probe did your module listed  in admin panel `system > configuration > advanced`

Comment: check the post now. I didn't created Tutsplus_Demo.xml

Comment: you have to create that  in etc/modules `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Tutsplus_Demo>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Tutsplus_Demo>
  </modules>
</config>`

Comment: yes. Its showing there.  If I comment this $customer= Mage::getModel("customer/session");

          //Mage_catalog_Model_Product
          //Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
          //$product = Mage::getModel("demo/product");
          // $product -> sayHello();
 and these lines then it works and show Hi on the screen,
$product = new tutsplus_Demo_Model_Product;
$product->sayHello();

Comment: Created new file Tutsplus_Demo.xml and pasted your xml code. Nothing happens same error.

Comment: check error log for xml error

Comment: @MineshPatel Where I'll find this xml error log?

Comment: @Probe i added the code with path kindly test and feedback

Comment: @Probe in var/log folder

Comment: @Qaisar By pasting the code in config.xml as you proposed. Its working now.